# Type Mismatch error when passing arrays to a function in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to write something in VBA that will compute the variance of a portfolio. I am stuck at the intermediate step of calculating the covariances of all the possible pairs in the portfolio.

I created a function that takes two arrays containing doubles as inputs and computes the covariannce. Code below, contains a call of another function "Mean" which is not shown.

```
Public Function CalcCov(A() As Double, B() As Double) As Double

Dim AvgA As Double
Dim AvgB As Double
Dim Cov As Double

AvgA = Mean(A)
AvgB = Mean(B)

Cov = 0
If UBound(A) = UBound(B) Then
    For I = 1 To UBound(A)
        Cov = Cov + ((A(I) - AvgA) * (B(I) - AvgB)) / UBound(A)
    Next I
ElseIf UBound(A) > UBound(B) Then
    For I = 1 To UBound(B)
        Cov = Cov + ((A(I) - AvgA) * (B(I) - AvgB)) / UBound(B)
    Next I
Else
    For I = 1 To UBound(A)
            Cov = Cov + ((A(I) - AvgA) * (B(I) - AvgB)) / UBound(A)
    Next I
End If

CalcCov = Cov

End Function
```

This function is called from the main subroutine shown below. The code below is supposed to create an array of doubles representing historical market data called tickerMD. Then, instances of tickerMD are supposed to be stored into an array of variants called tickersMD. Then a loop is supposed to run through tickersMD, and pass two arrays at at a time to the CalcCov function. I am getting a type mismatch error pointing to the starred portion of code. I do not understand why.

```
Public Sub Covariances()

Dim NumTickers As Double
Dim NumDays As Double
Dim NumCombinations As Double

NumTickers = Sheet4.Cells(1, 2)
NumDays = Sheet3.Cells(1, 2)
NumCombinations = (NumTickers ^ 2) / 2

Dim tickerMD() As Double' Holds the market-data for a single security
Dim tickersMD() As Variant  ' Holds the market-data arrays
Dim CovMarix() As Variant


ReDim tickersMD(NumTickers)
For Tickers = 0 To NumTickers - 1
    ReDim tickerMD(NumDays)
    For Days = 0 To NumDays - 1
         tickerMD(Days) = Sheet3.Cells(3 + Days, Find(Sheet4.Cells(Tickers + 1)))
    Next Days
    tickersMD(Tickers) = tickerMD
Next Tickers

ReDim CovMatrix(NumCombinations)
For I = 0 To NumTickers - 1
    For J = I + 1 To NumTickers - 1
        **CovMatrix(I) = CalcCov(tickersMD(I), tickersMD(J))**
    Next J
Next I


End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is you are passing only a single value of your arrays on this line `CovMatrix(I) = CalcCov(tickersMD(I), tickersMD(J))`.  Your `Function CalcCov` "wants" arrays not single values.

Comment: The array tickersMD is supposed to itself be composed of arrays. The loop that creates it is right above.

Comment: Decided to simply use the Collection object rather than arrays. I am curious about why I was having problems using arrays if anyone cares to explain, but I'm able to now continue with my project.

Comment: I prefer using `Collections` to deal with objects instead of arrays.  I should have suggested it before :)

Comment: Figured it out if anyone cares. Inside the last loop, need to declare two new double arrays and assign tickersMD(I) and tickersMD(J) respectively to them, then pass those arrays to CalcCov in order to have right type.

Comment: If you want to, I think you should post it as an answer and also you could add the alternative with the collections in case others run into the same problem.