# Type mismatch when changing argument types passed to a function

Tags: arrays, excel, compiler-errors, vba

**Situation:**

I have a function, `RemoveEmptyArrRowCol`, which accepts two arguments, one of which is an array (`tempArr`).

When the second argument was a **Long** everything was fine. When I changed the second argument to a **String** (and the associated call variable) I got:

> Type mismatch (Error 13)

So in the below code examples:

1. `Test1` runs fine
2. `Test2` fails

**Questions:**

1) Why is the behaviour different between the two?

2) How do I fix the second version so it behaves as per the first?

3) How will I future proof this for when I pass a dictionary value (array) as the 1st parameter, rather than reading directly from the worksheet?

**What I have tried:**

This appears to be a common question on SO and I have looked at a number of these questions; some of which I have put as references at the bottom of this question. I still, however, have not resolved why the first of these two sub works, but the second does not?

I played around with different combinations of:

1. Adding extra brackets
2. Explicitly declaring the type of `tempArr`: `Dim tempArr() As Variant`
3. Changing part of the function signature: `ByRef tempArr() As Variant`

After looking at @Fionnuala's answer to this question, [MS Access/VBA type mismatch when passing arrays to function/subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438671/passing-arrays-to-functions-in-vba), I decided to try using `Call`:

```
Call RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2(ws.Range("C4:I129").Value, tempStr)
```

This compiled but means I would need to change other parts of my code to ensure `tempArr` is correctly populated. If I were to do it this way, I might as well convert the function to a procedure.

As is, the flow is that I populate `tempArr`, in the test example, direct from the sheet and then hand off to another sub i.e.

```
tempArr = RemoveEmptyArrRowCol(ws.Range("C4:I129").Value, tempStr)
ArrayToSheet wb.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1"), tempArr
```

**Note re: Question 3:**

In the final version, I will be passing an array, pulled from a dictionary, as the first parameter i.e.

```
tempArr = RemoveEmptyArrRowCol( ArrayDict(tempStr), tempStr)
```

**Working version:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test1()

    Dim tempArr() 'variant

    Init

    Dim tempStr As String: tempStr = "Response Times"

    tempArr = RemoveEmptyArrRowCol(ws.Range("C4:I129").Value, categoryDict(tempStr & "Cols"))

End Sub

Private Function RemoveEmptyArrRowCol(ByRef tempArr As Variant, ByVal nCols As Long) As Variant

End Function
```

**Failing version:**

```
Public Sub Test2()

    Dim tempArr()

    Init

    Dim tempStr As String: tempStr = "Response Times"

    tempArr = RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2(ws.Range("C4:I129").Value, tempStr)

End Sub

Private Function RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2(ByRef tempArr As Variant, ByVal tempStr As String) As Variant

End Function
```

Example of the current full function:

```
Private Function RemoveEmptyArrRowCol(ByRef tempArr As Variant, ByVal tempStr As String) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 0

    Dim tempArr2()

    Dim totCol As Long
    Dim adjColTotal As Long

    totCol = categoryDict(tempStr & "Cols")
    adjColTotal = categoryDict(tempStr & "ColsAdj")

    Select Case tempStr

        Case "ResponseTimes", "NoCCPR"

            ReDim tempArr2(1 To 1000, 1 To adjColTotal)

            For i = 1 To UBound(tempArr, 1)

                If tempArr(i, 2) <> vbNullString Then   'process row

                    counter = counter + 1                'load row to temp array (counter becomes row count)

                    For j = 1 To totCol

                        Select Case j
                            Case Is < 4
                                tempArr2(counter, j) = tempArr(i, j)
                            Case Is > 4
                                tempArr2(counter, j - 1) = tempArr(i, j)
                        End Select

                    Next j

                End If

            Next i

            RemoveEmptyArrRowCol = RedimArrDimOne(tempArr2, adjColTotal, counter)

       Case "Incidents"

    End Select

End Function
```

Additional references:

1) [Passing arrays to functions in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438671/passing-arrays-to-functions-in-vba)

2) [Passing array to function returns compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417312/passing-array-to-function-returns-compile-error-type-mismatch-array-or-user-d)

3) [Type mismatch error when passing arrays to a function in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960025/type-mismatch-error-when-passing-arrays-to-a-function-in-excel-vba)

4) [Should I use Call keyword in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573597/should-i-use-call-keyword-in-vb-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your input and output, e.g. what is in the RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2 function. This is an option, in which `tempStr as String` is not failing:

```
Public Sub Test2()
    Dim tempArr()
    Dim tempStr As String: tempStr = "Response Times"
    tempArr = RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2(Range("C4:I129").Value, tempStr)
End Sub

Private Function RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2(ByRef tempArr As Variant, _
                                       ByVal tempStr As String) As Variant
    RemoveEmptyArrRowCol2 = Array(1, 2)
End Function
```

E.g., if you remove the returning value (Array(1,2), it fails) but it should fail, because it does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks. When refactoring I forgot to add a catch all for the return value.

Comment: @QHarr - thumbs up, welcome. In general there is a bit more concerning `ByRef` and `ByVal`. Take a look at my article here - http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-how-to-refer-a-function-byval-when-the-parameter-is-explicitly-referred-byref/ In your case, whenever a function is returning returning value, it takes the arguments `ByVal`, without caring that you have written `ByRef`.

Comment: So the entire function signature should be written using ByVal even though the array is altered?

Comment: @QHarr - depends how you are using it. If the function does not return value, but just does some changes in a variable, then `ByRef` is quite ok. Play a bit with your code, see the differences.

Comment: Just realised I refactored and am using a tempArr so should have used ByVal anyway here I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Define "Dim tempArr As Variant" not as Variant-Array with "()" 
Please show us your function "categoryDict" and "ArrayDict" 
"Call" is not nessesary! 
You access Values as follows:

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
For r = 1 To UBound(tempArr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(tempArr, 2)
        Debug.Print tempArr(r, c)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Apologies I somehow missed this